# Ignore prereq Makefile targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: target0 target1

target0:
    <command>

target1: target0
    <command>
```

How can I run `make target1` and force it to skip `target0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither GNU `make` nor any other `make` I know provides a means to ignore out-of-date prerequisites.  It is antithetical to `make`'s design and goals.  Targets that don't exist or (with GNU `make`) that are `.PHONY` are always considered out-of-date at the beginning of a run.  So, with that makefile, `make target1` will always build `target0` as well.

That you pose the question at all suggests that you have modeled something as a prerequisite that isn't really a prerequisite.  Perhaps you did so to aggregate targets, for example.  In that case, you could consider rewriting your makefile, maybe like so:

```
.PHONY: all target0 target1

target0:
    <command>

target1:
    <command>

all: target0 target1
```

With that, you can build just `target0` or just `target1` or both (`all`), as you choose, but you do need to request both when that's in fact what you want.  When you do request both, you will *probably* get `target0` built before `target1` unless you use the `-j` option.  But if you need to ensure that `target0` is built first when both are to be built, then you could do this, instead:

```
.PHONY: all target0 target1

target0:
    <command>

target1:
    <command>

all:
        make target0
        make target1
```

Comment: OK not the answer I was hoping for, but still helpful. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU make:

```sh
make -W target0 target1
```

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html)
on "Instead of Executing Recipes":

> Each ‘-W’ flag is followed by a file name. The given files’ modification 
> times are recorded by make as being the present time, although the actual 
> modification times remain the same.

> Without the ‘-n’ or ‘-q’ flag, when make is actually executing recipes, 
> the ‘-W’ flag can direct make to act as if some files had been modified, 
> without actually running the recipes for those files.